# Como comparar duas inclinações de retas provenientes de regressões polinomiais no R?

Tags: r

Oi, amigos.

Eu medi a temperatura do ar em cada hora de um dia em dois tratamentos: abaixo do dossel de 10 plantas e em 10 áreas abertas a uma distância padronizada de cada planta. Portanto, obtive duas regressões entre as horas do dia (preditora) e a temperatura do ar (resposta). As relações entre as variáveis tem forma de sino, por isso, preciso ajustar modelos polinomiais. Depois, preciso comparar a inclinação das retas. Posso usar uma ANCOVA para avaliar as regressões polinomiais e selecionar o melhor modelo, usando p<0,05 and maior valor de R²?

> ancova_null_model=lm(response~1*category, data)
>
> ancova1=lm(response~predictor*category, data)
>
> ancova2=lm(response~poly(predictor, 2)*category, data)
>
> ancova3=lm(response~poly(predictor, 3)*category, data)
>
> anova(ancova_null_model, ancova1, ancova2, ancova3)

```
summary(ancova1)$r.squared
summary(ancova2)$r.squared
summary(ancova3)$r.squared
```

Ou devo fazer duas regressões e comparar as inclinações usando outra análise? Nesse caso, como posso comparar as inclinações de regressões polinomiais em uma análise?

Todas as contribuição são bem vindas!

Comment: Infelizmente, dificilmente alguém irá responder esta pergunta por aqui, pois ela foge [dos tópicos que podem ser perguntados no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). O que sugiro é fazer esta pergunta na lista [R-br](http://r-br.2285057.n4.nabble.com/), pois teoria estatística não é um assunto off-topic por lá.

Comment: R é uma linguagem para fins específicos mas é uma linguagem e a pergunta (mal formulada sem dúvida) ainda é sobre programação.

Comment: Oi, Marcus. Obrigado pela sugestão. Vou enviar minhas dúvidas para a lista do R-br. Abraço!